# How to detect mobile that uses node api in a app

Tags: android, node.js, express, kotlin

I am using express `API` in my mobile app. The express server detects mobile **(using user-agent)** when API is tested through the mobile browser but the problem is with the app. Whenever I make an API request from the mobile app, the `user-agent` header has just `okhttp/3.12.1`.

How would I detect the mobile device in my case?

There might be a solution other than `user-agent`.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you're developing your mobile app with React-Native. "okhttp/3.12.1" is a correct user-agent for RN. Just check if user-agent is "okhttp/3.12.1" to recognize your own mobile app.

Alse you will probably need to recognize mobile browsers.

I use something like that:

```
mobile_browser_user_agent_sign_list = "Android", "iPhone", "Opera Mini", "Windows Phone", "Mobile Safari"


def is_mobile_device(user_agent):
    if "okhttp" in user_agent:
        return True
    for sign_item in mobile_browser_user_agent_sign_list:
        if sign_item in user_agent:
            return True
    return False
```